# Put a variable in this PHP Command

Tags: php

I currently have this in my php file:

```
$output = shell_exec('curl --anyauth --location-trusted -u: -c cookies.txt -b cookies.txt -v -k "https://someurl.com/search?term=11111111&warehouseId=123" >> log.txt');
```

I need to put a variable in the url so it looks like:

```
https://someurl.com/search?term=$VARIABLEGOESHERE&warehouseId=123
```

What would the syntax look like for that?

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. Is that variable to be resolved by php to a final URL you hand over to `cURL`, or is that mean to stay intact in the URL?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$VARIABLEGOESHERE = "111111";
$output = shell_exec("curl --anyauth --location-trusted -u: -c cookies.txt -b cookies.txt -v -k \"https://someurl.com/search?term=$VARIABLEGOESHERE&warehouseId=123\" >> log.txt");
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome @dkeeper09

Answer (score 2):

@Abhishek is right but a bit of explanation/terminology may be in order here.

The feature you are looking for is referred to, generically, as 'string interpolation' although the php documentation refers to it as 'variable parsing'. Scan about a quarter of the way down: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

and is used like:

```
$value = 'dog';
$string = "the lazy brown $value";
echo $string;
```

The echo will show `the lazy brown dog`

Note that, for interpolation to work, $string must be in double quotes. If we had:

```
$string = 'the lazy brown $value'
echo $string;
```

The echo will show `the lazy brown $value`

Comment: You should insist on the fact that it wont work with single quotes, I think that your note about it might not be explicit enough for somebody new to PHP.